# Cisco support status lookup by serial number

Tags: cisco, licensing, warranty

Many vendors allow you to look at the support status of a device with no information besides a serial number.  Does this exist for Cisco products?

Comment: Try this: https://cway.cisco.com/sncheck/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only if you already have your equipment associated with your account. The "Cisco Service Contract Center" will let you look up support status by serial number.

Here is the link:
 http://www.cisco.com/web/services/ordering/cscc/index.html

Comment: The problem is that it's not my equipment; it's a customer's.  As such, *I* don't have a contract on it.  (Sorry about the previous half-comment.)